# trying to get omniauth-facebook to work undefined method `user_id' for nil:NilClass rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, omniauth

I am using ryan bates facebook authentication railscast and this post on coderwall to implement a login feature with omniauth-facebook

https://coderwall.com/p/bsfitw

so for my gemfile I have these two

```
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
```

this is my omniauth.rb

```
OmniAuth.config.logger = Rails.logger

Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :facebook, 'commentedoutappid', 'commentedoutsecretid'
end
```

my routes look like this

```
  match 'auth/:provider/callback', to: 'sessions#create', via: [:get, :post]
  match 'auth/failure', to: redirect('/'), via: [:get, :post]
  match 'signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', as: 'signout', via: [:get, :post]

  resources :movies do 
    resources :reviews
  end 
  root to: 'movies#index'
```

here is my sessions controller

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    user = User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])
    session[:user_id] = current_user.user_id 
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```

here is my users model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_initialize.tap do |user|
      user.provider = auth.provider 
      user.uid = auth.uid
      user.name = auth.info.name
      user.oauth_token = auth.credentials.oauth_token 
      user.oauth_expires_at = Time.at(auth.credentials.expires_at)
      user.save
     end
   end 
end
```

here is my users table

```
  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "provider"
    t.string   "uid"
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "oauth_token"
    t.datetime "oauth_expires_at"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
  end
```

I have these links in my application.html.erb

```
<div id="user-widget">
  <% if current_user %>
    Signed in as <strong><%= current_user.name %></strong>!
    <%= link_to "Sign out", signout_path, id: "sign_out" %>
  <% else %>
    <%= link_to "Sign in with facebook", "/auth/facebook", id: "sign_in" %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

when I click on the link which directs to auth/facebook

I am getting `undefined method`user_id' for nil:NilClass` in my sessions controller.

oh I also have a current_user helper method

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end 
  helper_method :current_user
end
```

so far I totally understand the flow but don't understand the error. I totally follow the guide from top to bottom.

I started off with a blank rails 4 app. I have even tried installing devise so there is a current_user given but I ended up uninstalling devise because they were clashing.

Comment: Did my answer resolve your issue? Let me know the results and query, if any.

Comment: it probably did but unfortunately I didn't have time for it yet. I will definitely come back to give you the credit in a bit if it works!

Answer (score 2):

Update the `create` action in `SessionsController` as below:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    user = User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"]) ## Setting "user" here
    session[:user_id] = user.id  ## Changed this to use the set "user"
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```

Use `user.id` instead of `current_user.user_id`. Logically you would be having `id` column in `users` table and NOT `user_id`.

As you have assigned

`user = User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])`

you need to set `session[:user_id] = user.id` as `user` variable has instance of currently saved user with `omniauth`.

On the side note, I just checked the link that you provided in the question out of curiosity and found that it is clearly mentioned to use `session[:user_id] = user.id`. You must have missed it but my above explanation would give you an idea of why it was that way.

Comment: Following each and every step but still nothing. A bit help please.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36114675/authentication-failure-omniauth